# Ember - Minify CSS File in public Folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, minify

When I build my `super-rentals` Ember app with command `ember build -prod` all css files in `app\styles` folder are minified but css files in `public\assets\css` folder are not minified. So how I could minify all css file in `public\assets\css` folder.

Comment: This is expected. Everything in `public` will just be copied to the output dir. You should not place there anything that you want compile. Consider the `vendor` folder for this.

Comment: Oh, this is a good information. I don't know much about Ember Compile process. I have searched in `emberjs.com` but could not found any doc mentions about this.

Comment: Visit ember-cli.com for docs regarding the CLI. I think these will be merged into the main site this year.